# MySQL select occurence by count

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with two columns like this:

```
source_cid     inchikey
----------     --------
 1             qqmn
 2             qqmn
 3             ccmm
```

Now I want to select source_cids which have same inchikeys

Here is my query:

```
SELECT source_cid, count(*) as c
FROM inchikey
GROUP BY inchikey HAVING count(*)>1
```

This code runs forever. How can I modify it?

Comment: How many records do you have in your table? Does it really only have two columns, or is this a simplified schema for the purpose of the question?

Comment: That is a very good question. Also, what does forever constitute to? 1-2 minutes? How many records do you have. What is your real table? Or is it a view?

Comment: There are 4 columns and 31451649 rows in my table. This query runs for two days in my python shell.

Comment: Please SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename You probably need to add indexes for a start.

Comment: I've already added hash indexes for all columns.

Comment: My comment still stands, if you show use your create table we can replicate it and debug why it is taking so long and suggest how to speed it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, as Anigel has stated we need to see your create statements and you should be using indexes.

Secondly, your query does not display all the rows that should be displayed.

See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a810d/7

```
SELECT source_cid, count(*) as c
FROM inchikey
GROUP BY inchikey HAVING count(*)>1;
```

Unfortunately only row with source_cids 1 is outputted.

```
select * from inchikey i,
(
SELECT i2.inchikey, count(i2.source_cid) as c
FROM inchikey i2
GROUP BY i2.inchikey HAVING count(i2.source_cid)>1
 ) as cd
where cd.inchikey = i.inchikey;
```

With this, rows with 1 and 2 are outputted.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a repeating index on (source_cid, inchikey) on table inchikey, then try running the query:

```
SELECT inchikey, group_concat(distinct source_cid) source_cids, count(*) as c
FROM inchikey
GROUP BY inchikey HAVING count(distinct source_cid)>1
```

(Your existing query will only show one source_cid for each repeating inchikey.)